# Sharing variables between node preprocess and page preprocess

Tags: 6, theming

Both of my preprocess files use the $vars array. I assigned a new element to the $vars array in page preprocess but I can't access this variable in node preprocess. I tried doing it the other way around and had the same problem. How can I get around this?

Comment: What's a preprocess file?

Comment: My theme has 2 files, preprocess-node.inc and preprocess-page.inc that are used to pass values to node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node object itself can be used to share information across these two functions. In your template_node_preprocess() override do something like:

```
$node = $variables['node'];
$node->my_data = my_data_function();
$variables['my_data'] = $node->my_data;
```

Then in template_preprocess_page() override write:

```
if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
  $variables['my_data'] = $variables['node']->my_data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be useful to have this piece of code here. This is how you can pass variables from page to node. in `THEME_preprocess_page`

```
if(isset($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'])){
    $keys = array_keys($vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes']); 
    $vars['page']['content']['system_main']['nodes'][$keys[0]]['#node']->variable_name = value; 
}
```

In `node.tpl.php` you can `print $variable_name`