# Node view mode in page template suggestions

Tags: 8, theming

I would like **page** template suggestions when a **node** is using a custom view mode.

I think this would happen in `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`.

I have already been able to get page-level template suggestions based on the node's content type, so it seems like I should be able to snag the name of the custom view mode?

I'm not good at this part of Drupal at all, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to turn on twig theme suggestion (google it) and clone a suggested template in your sub-theme

Comment: I understand Twig template suggestions. There is not a template suggestion for a PAGE where the NODE uses a CUSTOM View Mode. This is why a normal template suggestion won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by first setting a custom node parameter by overriding template_preprocess_node in your .theme file. For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(array &$variables, $hook) {
  if(isset($variables['view_mode'])) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $node->current_view_mode = $variables['view_mode'];
  }
}
```

When this is added you can access the custom parameter in hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter() page as $node->current_view_mode.

For example:

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->current_view_mode;
 }
}
```

You may have to add some extra validation to ensure $node->current_view_mode has a useful value.

See also [Sharing variables between node preprocess and page preprocess](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/sharing-variables-between-node-preprocess-and-page-preprocess) & [Get node's view mode within template_preprocess_page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277780/get-nodes-view-mode-within-template-preprocess-page/313615#313615)

Answer (score 1):

The hook `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK` is the one you should implement.

When you have a ***node* of type *page*** (labeled as *Basic Page* from the [*default profile*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/understanding-drupal/content-types)), then the *HOOK* is *node* and the specific *hook* you would implement is **`hook_theme_suggestions_node(array $variables)`**

As @pinueve points out, there is already a specific *suggestion* that includes the custom display mode: `node--page--CUSTOM_VIEW_MODE.html.twig`.

Also, as @pinueve suggests, the easy way to find the template suggestions is by [enabling the debugging mode](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates). I tested this using a custom view mode called `customvm` that I created, so I can see these suggestions in the browser by inspecting the source code:

```
* node--17--customvm.html.twig
* node--17.html.twig
* node--page--customvm.html.twig
* node--page.html.twig
* node--customvm.html.twig
x node.html.twig
```

**Alter hook**

Note that there is also an *alter* version of the hook `[HOOK_theme_suggestions_node(array &$suggestions, array $variables)][3]`, you should use this if you are trying to alter the existing suggestions, maybe changing the priorities.

**Suggestions for a *page* from a custom *controller***

The *page* *HOOK* is meant to be used when the output comes from a custom *controller* and *route*, like the one in this example:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example

In this case the *HOOK* is *page* and you would implement these hooks:

- HOOK_theme_suggestions_page(array $variables)
- HOOK_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array
  $variables)

Comment: Can you elaborate on using `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter` for theming page.html.twig when a custom view modes is used.

Comment: @ymdahi, For example, if you create the file ```node--page--MY-CUSTOM-VIEW-MODE.html.twig```, Drupal will pick it up. (```page``` is the node type). does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I meant creating a custom suggestion for `page.html.twig` and not node `node.html.twig` - does that make sense? Or can I override page.html.twig using `node--page---`

Comment: I have the same question @ymdahi has. How do I get the view_mode variable in the theme_suggestions_page_alter? This does not work: $view_mode = $variables['view_mode']; I don't understand the content at the link you provided at the end of your answer.