# Get node's view mode within template_preprocess_page

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

We have to get the current node's `view_mode` from within the `mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables)` hook. When we tried the following we could not get the `view_mode` after performing some validation to make sure we have a `node` object.

In the `Basic page`, we have a `Related Articles` section that is an entity reference to the `Article` content type. This returns multiple nodes depending upon the page and we want to ensure the `template_preprocess_node()` hook is ran only once.

**How can we get the current node's `view_mode` from within the `template_preprocess_page(&$variables)` hook?**

Here is what we tried to do

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if(isset($node) && is_object($node) {
    // Tried printing variables but cannot find `view_mode`
    ksm($node);
  }
}
```

Comment: @4k4 I updated the question with more information regarding our pages. We essentially added an `entity reference` to the `basic page` so we just want to be sure the hook is only run once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible you are using the wrong hook. `hook_preprocess_page()` is not for the content type `page`. Use a preprocess hook for nodes and check the content type:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->getType() === 'page') {
    $view_mode = $variables['view_mode'];
    // preprocess only nodes of the content type "Basic Page"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually in need of getting current node's view mode in `hook_preprocess_html()`. Can it be done? The `node` can be retrieved by `$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');`. but that node wouldn't contain the current context, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to put a class based on view mode onto my pages.  I seem to remember that view mode is handled separately from the node data.  My solution was actually based on using the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) submodule Switch View Mode (was already using DS).  This module creates a new base field in the entity and sets the view mode to it.

This let me use the following code to create the class:

```
$view_mode = $node->ds_switch->value;
if (!empty($view_mode)) {
   $variables['page_class'] .= " node-view-{$view_mode}";
}
```

This solution won't work with out the module.  A bit of tracing on how this works shows that it is based on using [hook_entity_view_mode_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/8.2.x) to get the view mode and add it to the ds_switch field on the node.

This field seems to be added by using the hook_entity_base_field_info().  See the ds_switch_view_mode.module file in the Display Suite code for details on this.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a custom node parameter by overriding template_preprocess_node in your .theme file. For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(array &$variables, $hook) {
  if(isset($variables['view_mode'])) {
    $node = $variables['node'];
    $node->current_view_mode = $variables['view_mode'];
  }
}
```

When this is added you can access the custom parameter in template_preprocess page as $node->current_view_mode.

See also [Sharing variables between node preprocess and page preprocess](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/sharing-variables-between-node-preprocess-and-page-preprocess)

Comment: **This!** I've been trying to do this and thought it just wasn't possible. So simple. 

Using this approach, you can then access view mode in template_preprocess_page() with `$view_mode = $variables['node']->current_view_mode;`

If the OP is trying to get access to the view_mode in `template_preprocess_page()`, this should be the accepted answer. 

**Thank you @batigolix!**

Comment: This doesn't work if the page is invalidated and the node is not, for example by a cache tag other than the node cache tag or a cache context only set on page level.